# not able to run Django in windows 10

Tags: django

I have just installed Django in anaconda. I am running it in windows 10, right now i am trying to run the django server. For this when i `manage.py runserver` i get a popup window which asks me to chose how to open this site. The screenshot is below:

[image]

Initially i chose windows explorer but since then i am getting a window which list the file as downloads. How can i run this file?
I have also tried `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` in chrome but i get "the site cannot be reached page". How can i fix this?

Comment: Run this with `python3 manage.py runserver`. It thinks that `manage.py` is an executable, and likely it does not understand the sha-bang.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you solved this thanks!